# Is there a way to make images vertical from left facing or right facing?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have input images that are either right-oriented i.e (90 degrees from the center clockwise) or left-oriented i.e (270 or -90 degrees from the center clockwise). I need to convert either of these images to vertical orientation. I have tried to do it using the Pillow library but nothing seems to be working.

**I need to know the orientation first. If it's right facing, I rotate by 270 clockwise; if it's left facing, I turn by just 90 clockwise.**

[image: This is my input image here]

**I need to make it vertical**

[image: This is how I want the image]

Any orientation, be it left or right needs to be verticallly alligned.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-rotate-method/?ref=lbp

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki No, I need to know the orientation. If its right facing then I rotate by 270 and if its left facing I rotate by just 90 clockwise

Answer (score -1):

You can use cv2.flip(src, dst, flipCode)

Comment: Yes, I tried that but how to determine the orientation of the image before flipping? I need to know it right to flip accordingly.

Comment: I think you mean `cv2.rotate`

Comment: No, I need to know the orientation. If its right facing then I rotate by 270 and if its right facing I rotate by just 90 clockwise

Comment: Does this image https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/alcohol-ink-texture-fluid-abstract-background-art-design-131606737.jpg need to be rotated left, right or not at all? Determining the rotation of an image is subjective.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki But I'm dealing with human images, any orientation other than vertical is not acceptable. I need to make them vertical irrespective of the orientation

Comment: How, run a face detection and try to extract the orientation, but if somebody is lying an a bed you might end up with a wrongly rotated image